# background image of a div renders differently on server but not on localhost

Tags: html, css

The background image I added on a div in a page shows normally stretched with no repeat on my local host, but on the server it is showing repeated. On another page, which is similar to this one but with different color scheme and an image with same dimensions, it shows up normally. 
This is local host:

[image: This is what it looks like on local host]

This is on the server:

[image]

and this is the other page with similar image which renders perfectly on both local host and server:

[image]

The website is [here.](http://www.cmata.in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you set background at 2 places.

First here:

```
.parallax_banner2aa {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(../../images/parallax/intro-2aa.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

With `backgroud-size: cover` in:

```
.parallax {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: 50% 0;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And the second here without `background-size`:

```
.parallax_banner2aa:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  background: url(../../images/parallax/intro-2aa.jpg)  no-repeat;
}
```

So you just need to remove second background or add `backgroud-size: cover` to it then your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Your background is present twice in this page.

- In `.parallax_banner2aa`
- In `.parallax_banner2aa::before`

I would suggest you to remove the background present in ::before.

[With the background in ::before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46hjj.jpg)
[Without the background in ::before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIMEW.png)

Answer (score 1):

The overlaying small image is coming from another place, because If you try to temporarily remove the actual background, the overlay keeps in place:

[image: See image]